# Abrir uma página dentro de uma página

Tags: html

Por exemplo, tem um botão que leva para outra página, mas gostaria que abrisse na mesma, tipo uma caixa de diálogo, com botão de fechar, maximizar e também que ela ficasse em destaque, (sem poder interagir com elementos fora dela).

Já fiz algo parecido com isso com dhtxml, mas é possível fazer com CSS e/ou JavaScript?

Também gostaria de perguntar se tem como centralizar algo, como um formulário automaticamente dependendo do tamanho da tela, ou é só no braço px por px?

Comment: Você diz... [iframe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iframe)?

Comment: da pra fazer um ajax load em uma div

Answer (score 2):

Conheço somente o IFrame via HTML:

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

Em Javascript, você tem que baixar a página via chamada GET e definir o innerHTML (por exemplo) de um div desta página. Mas na prática não sei exatamente como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Para centralizar, tenta colocar esse código na Div

```css
.Video {
  margin: 0;
  /* removing the default ul margin */
  padding: 0;
  /* removing the default ul padding */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Video">
  Elemento qualquer
</div>
```